# MySQL started to consume about 40% of system CPU time and got unresponsive suddenly

Tags: mysql, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage

I use Debian 6.0.3 x86_64 and MySQL 5.5.20-1~dotdeb.0-log from the Dotdeb repository. MySQL process started to consume a lot of "sy" CPU time serveral hours ago according to [this](http://prntscr.com/bryyz) graph. I was not able to connect to running `mysqld` process and had to kill it. I found nothing useful in logs. My setup seems to be quite common (I assume Dotdeb just redistributes stock MySQL versions) and I have never seen anything like this before.
What is the possible root cause of this? How can I prevent this situation in the future?

Comment: Have you looked into the leap second bug?

Comment: Sure. But the system was restarted on Jul 06 so the leap second bug should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it happens again, run `strace -p <PID> -T` or swap the `-T` with `-c`.

The `-T` option prints a time delta after each system call that lets you know how long it took.  If you see particular calls like `stat()` and `open()` taking a long time you can infer one thing and if you see ones like `semop()` or `poll()` taking a long time you can infer something else.  The same goes for seeing a lot of them but this can be more difficult to see which is where the next option comes in.

The `-c` option waits until either the program finishes or you break out with `ctrl-c` and then prints a summary of all the system calls and how much time was spent in each type.

With any luck, this should let you know what MySQL is doing.  Then you just have to figure out what to do about it.

Comment: In addition to this, although it's kind of late now, MySQL has an option to log slow queries which can help in diagnosing this kind of thing.

Comment: @bahamat, it's a pity a comment can't be downvoted. ;-)